# Count records by quarter across a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure what the proper way to phrase this question is but I'm hoping this makes sense.  I have a query:

```
SELECT 
     c.ID,
     c.Name,
     c.DateAdded,
     c.LastContact
FROM 
     computers AS c
WHERE 
     LENGTH(DateAdded) > 1
ORDER BY 
     DateAdded ASC;
```

Which Returns:

```
ID  Name    DateAdded           LastContact
1   MUTHER  9/2/2012 1:23       5/17/2016 13:57
5   VGER    12/19/2012 10:44    5/17/2016 13:56
7   HELPER  1/13/2013 18:09     5/17/2016 13:57
9   JARVIS  1/15/2013 0:28      7/31/2015 0:20
12  PHLFS1  1/17/2013 18:41     2/17/2013 13:37
```

I am able to count the date that computers were added by Quarter with this query:

```
SELECT 
     YEAR(DateAdded) AS YEAR, 
     QUARTER(DateAdded) AS QUARTER, 
     COUNT(ComputerID) AS 'added-during-qtr'
FROM 
     computers
WHERE 
     LENGTH(DateAdded) > 1
GROUP BY 
     YEAR(DateAdded), 
     QUARTER(DateAdded)
ORDER BY 
     YEAR(DateAdded), 
     QUARTER(DateAdded)
```

Which gives me a count of when the were activated:

```
year    quarter added-during-qtr
2012    3       1
2012    4       1
2013    1       3
```

But **NOT** if they were active during the Quarter or Not, which is what I'm really looking for:

```
year    quarter active-during-qtr
2012    3       1
2012    4       2
2013    1       5
2013    2       4
```

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question the right way or not but at the end of the day, I want to count the number of computers that were 'active' between DateAdded and LastContact, sorted by year and quarter.  Ideally without having to manually add ranges in a case statement.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know if a computer was "active" then? Is there another column that you do not show in your post right now or is it defined in a different way? One needs to know this information to be able to help you with your question.

Comment: I think the same as @Fuzzzzel. Should be a `Deactivate` Column as well other wise I cant explain how after 5 computer were activate by 1st quarter of 2013 then the next quarter only 4

Comment: you are looking for **2013    2       4** but there is no data for 2013-Q2 in your table

Comment: I included that on purpose.  I am counting if a pc "checked in" between DateAdded and LastContact.  If a pc is active during the quarter in question, count it.

Comment: When you say "active" in a certain year/quarter, do you mean the computer was added in that year/quarter or later, and that its last contact was in that year/quarter or prior?  In other words, a computer is active in period X if X is between `DateAdded` and `LastContact`?

Comment: You're going to have to use a `recursive query` to create a date set that spans the range you want to look for.

Comment: @PaulL Exactly.  A computer is considered active in period X if period X is between DateAdded & LastContact.

Comment: @JimJawn okay, but then where are you getting your periods from in your stated desired result set?  The first three rows are all periods that match one of the `DateAdded` columns, but the fourth one doesn't.  It's just a random period somewhere between the first `DateAdded` and the last `LastContact`.  But you didn't list **all** periods between them, so why that one in particular?

Comment: Alex's Fiddle works.  I think you can see what I'm going for in there.  Let's say a computer as added in 2/1/2013 and goes offline on 5/1/2013, so it's checking in for 3 months, Feb, Mar, Apr.  

2012-Q4 = False
2013-Q1 = True (it checked in starting on 2/1)
2013-Q2 = True (it checked in on 4/1)
2013-Q3 = False (it didn't check in on 6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still can't get your logic why you expect something for 2nd quarter of 2013.

But here is my attempt:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce133d/7

```
SELECT 
  p.year,
  p.quarter,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
FROM (
  SELECT 
  YEAR(DateAdded) AS YEAR, 
  QUARTER(DateAdded) AS QUARTER,
  CONCAT(YEAR(DateAdded),QUARTER(DateAdded)) period
    FROM computers
  WHERE LENGTH(DateAdded) > 1
  GROUP BY YEAR(DateAdded), QUARTER(DateAdded)
  ORDER BY YEAR(DateAdded), QUARTER(DateAdded)
  ) p #periods
LEFT JOIN computers c
ON p.period>=CONCAT(YEAR(c.DateAdded),QUARTER(c.DateAdded))
GROUP BY p.period
```

**Update** According to your last comments this modifications could be done:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c323e/5

```
SELECT 
  p.year,
  p.quarter,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    y.year,
    q.quarter,
    CONCAT(y.year,q.quarter) period
  FROM (SELECT 2012 AS year UNION SELECT 2013 ) y 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS quarter UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ) q
  ON 1
  ) p #periods
LEFT JOIN computers c
ON p.period>=CONCAT(YEAR(c.DateAdded),QUARTER(c.DateAdded))
  AND p.period<=CONCAT(YEAR(c.LastContact),QUARTER(c.LastContact))
GROUP BY p.period
```

and if you need to limit the period you can add `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY p.period` like this:

```
WHERE p.period<='20132'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c323e/7

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to track if a computer checked into our server during a given range.  If I added them on 1/1/2015 and the computer stopped checking on 4/15/2015, I would count it for Q1 & Q2 but it would drop off of my count for Q3.

Comment: Do you ever read what I did ask about? *If I added them on 1/1/2015* this part is very clear. but in your sample provided there is no such data. The only periods are `Q3-2012, Q4-2012 and Q1-2013` check your post.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I did read what you asked and I think my question is a little unclear.  The query should count the number of computers that "checked in" during a quarter.  I have the date they started checking in, the date they stopped checking in and the quarter I want to test for.  That's the 2013 Q2 result, I'm looking for.  Only 4 computers checked in between 4/1/2013 and 6/30/2013.

Comment: This works!  Ok, I see what's going on, you're appending a year and quarter value for each PC if it falls between the range and then grouping by that period in the where clause.  Brilliant!